# How can I return a value to my ViewModel from CoroutineScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

My activity wants to insert a new element on my database using Room, so the activity delegate this task to a ViewModel class passing the Entity object. The activity wants the value back of the id autogenerated by the database so the object can be updated in real-time.
So, the ViewModel class wants to launch a coroutine on the IO pool thread that uses an insert Dao method that returns the new id value.
Finally, my question is: how can I return the value from the coroutine to the ViewModel method?

This is my code into the ViewModel class:

```
//return autogenerated id
fun insert(fiscalcode: Fiscalcode): Int {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        db.fiscalcodeDao().insert(fiscalcode)
        //return autogenerated id
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using room? If yes, you don't need to give different dispatcher, for it to work

Comment: If the `insert()` method returns the new ID, then your Activity should be observing a `LiveData<SomeState>` from the ViewModel, so the VM would `_someState.postValue(YourState(id))` and the activity observing it would react to it, as described [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: Use `viewModelScope.async { ... }` instead and call it from your activity inside 
 a `lifecycleScope.launch { ... }` block. Or just make your `insert` function suspending and call it from your activity inside a `lifecycleScope.launch { ... }` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix suspending and non-suspending worlds.
You could make a variable in your viewmodel.

```
val _rowId = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)
val rowId: StateFlow<Int>
    get() = _rowId

fun insert(fiscalcode: Fiscalcode): Int {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
       _rowId.value = db.fiscalcodeDao().insert(fiscalcode)
    }
}
```

And you can collect this `rowId` Flow in your activity.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.rowId
             .flowWithLifecycle(this, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
             .collect { rowId -> ... }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bad practice but as per your question if you want to return you can use
runBlocking for same

```
val id = runBlocking {
   db.fiscalcodeDao().insert(fiscalcode)
}
```